# NotImplementedError: range_state_int64 cannot be represented as a Numpy dtype

Tags: python, python-2.7, numba

I am trying to write a function that initialises an array and shuffles it before returning. 
    import numba as nb

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def test(x):
    ind = np.array(range(len(x)))
    np.random.shuffle(ind)
    return ind
```

Error message said that I used unsupported features or data types:

```
NotImplementedError: range_state_int64 cannot be represented as a Numpy dtype
```

Does numba supports numpy.random.shuffle() or not? How to revise it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with `random.shuffle`, because [numba supports the random module out of the box](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html?highlight=shuffle#random).

The issue here is that [numba cannot support the `range` object](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions) (because it is a python object) when the `nopython` flag has been set. Substitute `range` with `np.arange` instead:

```
@nb.njit(cache=True)  # same as @nb.jit(nopython=True, ...)
def test(x):
    ind = np.arange(len(x))
    np.random.shuffle(ind)
    return ind

test([1, 2, 3])
# array([1, 0, 2])
```

Comment: Specifically, see the note on `range` in https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions

Comment: Thank you, cs95. I just read it and understood now that numba requires homogeneous data types in a list. I did not know this before.